# Unbalanced Anova in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, anova

I'm kind of new to Matlab and I am not quite sure how this is done.

Given an unbalanced dataset like so:

```
g1   g2   g3
____________
3    4    2
2    1    6
6    3    1
5    6
     9
```

How would you perform an ANOVA on this dataset? It is currently saved as three arrays.

`anova1(SomeDataset)` works fine if all the columns are the same length, but Matlab doesn't like concatenating arrays of different lengths. Do I need to use a different data structure? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use anova1 as usual, but you need to group your data and tell MATLAB that they are grouped and it should work:

```
clc
clear

x1 = [3;2;6;5];
x2 = [4;1;3;6;9];
x3 = [2;6;1];

data = [x1' x2' x3']; %// Create row vector with your data
group = {'G1','G1','G1','G1','G2','G2','G2','G2','G2','G3','G3','G3'}; %// set the groups according to the data above

[p1] = anova1(data, group,'off') %// Use the 'off' option to prevent the table/box plot from showing up.

p1 =

    0.7119
```

**EDIT:** Mhh after playing around it looks like if you fill the vectors with NaNs so that they are the same length it works; by that I mean it gives the same p-value and the box plot looks identical. I don't know if it's valid though so I'd go with the first method :)

Code:

```
z1 = [3;2;6;5;NaN];
z2 = [4;1;3;6;9];
z3 = [2;6;1;NaN;NaN];

Z = [z1 z2 z3]
[p2] = anova1(Z)
```

Comment: Thanks Benoit! I figured it out using grouping, but I like the NaN method. It might be quicker for larger datasets. Also, the repmat function comes in handy for setting up groups.

Comment: Great then glad you figured it out! And you're right the NaN method can prove quite useful for large datasets :)